# apply conditions to df.groupby() to filter out duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to groupby and filter out duplicates in a pandas dataframe based on conditions. My dataframe looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,4,4],'Date':['1/1/2001','1/1/1999','1/1/2010','1/1/2004','1/1/2000','1/1/2001','1/1/2000'], 'type':['yes','yes','yes','yes','no','no','no'], 'source':[3,1,1,2,2,2,1]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('ID')
df

    Date    source  type
ID          
1   2001-01-01  3   yes
1   1999-01-01  1   yes
2   2010-01-01  1   yes
2   2004-01-01  2   yes
3   2000-01-01  2   no
4   2001-01-01  2   no
4   2000-01-01  1   no
```

I need to groupby ID and type and anywhere type == yes keep the most current record only if it has the highest source. If the most current record does not have the highest source keep both records 
Desired output:

```
    Date    source  type
ID          
1   2001-01-01  3   yes
2   2010-01-01  1   yes
2   2004-01-01  2   yes
3   2000-01-01  2   no
4   2001-01-01  2   no
4   2000-01-01  1   no
```

I have tried using transform but cannot figure out how to apply conditions:

```
    grouped = df.groupby(['ID','type'])['Date'].transform(max)
    df = df.loc[df['Date'] == grouped]
    df

        Date    source  type
    ID          
    1   2001-01-01  3   yes
    2   2010-01-01  2   yes
    3   2000-01-01  2   no
    4   2001-01-01  2   no
```

any help is greatly appreciated

WEN here is the problem if I have a dataframe with  more rows (I have about 70 columns and 5000 rows) it does not take into consideration the source max.

```
    Date    source  type
ID          
1   2001-01-01  3   yes
1   1999-01-01  1   yes
2   2010-01-01  1   yes
2   2004-01-01  2   yes
3   2000-01-01  2   no
4   2001-01-01  1   yes
4   2000-01-01  2   yes
```

using you code I get:

```
Date    source  type
ID          
1   2001-01-01  3   yes
2   2010-01-01  1   yes
2   2004-01-01  2   yes
3   2000-01-01  2   no
4   2001-01-01  1   yes
```

it should be:

```
    Date    source  type
ID          
1   2001-01-01  3   yes
2   2010-01-01  1   yes
2   2004-01-01  2   yes
3   2000-01-01  2   no
4   2001-01-01  1   yes
4   2000-01-01  2   yes
```

Comment: Your desired output seems to have an extra record (the 3rd one).

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That is my desired output. the condition is anywhere type == yes keep the most current record only if it has the highest source. if the most current record does not have the highest source keep both records

Comment: That's slightly different from what you said (and my interpretation of what you said), but alright, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: My apologies, I fixed the phrasing of the conditions in the question.

Comment: Is there any thing wrong with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will need `pd.concat`

```
grouped = df.groupby(['type'])['Date'].transform(max)# I change this line seems like you need groupby type
s = df.loc[df['Date'] == grouped].index

#here we split the df into two part , one need to drop the not match row , one should keep all row    
pd.concat([df.loc[df.index.difference(s)].sort_values('Date').groupby('ID').tail(1),df.loc[s]]).sort_index()
             Date  source type
    ID                        
    1  2001-01-01       3  yes
    2  2010-01-01       1  yes
    2  2004-01-01       2  yes
    3  2000-01-01       2   no
    4  2001-01-01       2   no
    4  2000-01-01       1   no
```

Update

```
grouped = df.groupby(['type'])['source'].transform(max)
s = df.loc[df['source'] == grouped].index

    pd.concat([df.loc[s].sort_values('Date').groupby('ID').tail(1),df.loc[df.index.difference(s)]]).sort_index()
Out[445]: 
          Date  source type
ID                         
1   2001-01-01       3  yes
2   2010-01-01       1  yes
2   2004-01-01       2  yes
3   2000-01-01       2   no
4   2001-01-01       1  yes
4   2000-01-01       2  yes
```

Comment: Although this reproduces the desired output it does not on a larger scale. If I add 2 more rows following the same format for ID 2 it only keeps the most current date. It is not filtering based on the conditions I need above. I will update my questions with an example.

Comment: it did not filter out the correct rows see the should be at the bottom of my updated questions. I really appreciate the effort

Comment: @Chris this one `pd.concat([df.loc[s].sort_values('Date').groupby('ID').tail(1),df.loc[df.index.difference(s)]]).sort_index()`

Comment: I did look at that one; it returns `ID 1,1,2,3,4,4` it should return `ID 1,2,2,3,4,4` please take another look at the last output in the updated question.

Comment: @Chris OK , check it : -)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170550/discussion-between-chris-and-wen).